# Retrieve row names of maximum and second maximum values of a column in R

Tags: r

We have this df

```
# We create the df
x <- c(1,33,5,2,56,1)
y <- c(4,358,57,3,32,2)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))

rownames(df) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")
```

The df is:

```
   x    y
a  1    4
b 33  358
c  5   57
d  2    3
e 56   32
f  1    2
```

I would like to retrieve row names of the maximum value and its second highest value from the column `x`, and the same row names from the `y` column.

So the result will be `e` and `b` from the `x` column and `b` and `c` from the `y` column.

I tried these codes, but unsuccessfully.

```
rownames(df)[max(df$x)] # for the maximum value
nx <- length(df$x) # length of the x column
rownames(df)[sort(df$x, partial=nx-1)[nx-1]] # for the second max value
```

However, the results of the previous three code lines are:

```
NA  # what's wrong?
6   # yeah, it is 6
"e" # nope, the second max is "b"
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close: just locate the values

```
rownames(df[df$x == max(df$x),]) # for the maximum value
nx <- length(df$x) # length of the x column
rownames(df[df$x == sort(df$x, partial=nx-1)[nx-1],]) # for the second max value
```

Comment: Perfect. Now I see where were my faults.

Answer (score 3):

We could loop over the columns, `order` it in decreasing, use that index to get the rownames, subset the first two

```
sapply(df, function(x) head(row.names(df)[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)], 2))
#      x   y  
#[1,] "e" "b"
#[2,] "b" "c"
```

Comment: Fantastic, this is a more elegant code to retrieve the same information.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `dplyr::filter` and base R `quantile` function.

```
df %>%  
  filter(variable > quantile(.$variable, 0.975, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: The question asks for only top two results, in this answer, quantile returns two results only due to luck of the example dataset, and might return many results with another dataset.